# c# remove elements on a list by comparing with other lists

Tags: c#, linq

I'm doing this with C#. I have 3 lists that will get filled from different databases. i want to compare those 3 lists with a my principal List, if an item in my principal list is not in one of those 3 list, i want to remove it from the principal.

Example:

```
var list1 = (from a in db.candyStore 
         select brand)
var list2 = (from b in db.AnotherCandyStore
         select brand)

var list3 = (from c in db.supermarket
         select brand)

var princiapalList = (from a in db.candyStore 
     select brand)
```

Any ideas o how to do this??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Small point, but you don't have 3 lists here, you have 3 sets of `IQueryable<T>`. They may act like lists sometimes but be careful as they are not that simple!

Comment: You are right, i tried to remove an item and i got exception: collection was modified, ennumeration operation cannot execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ExceptWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `HashSet<T>`:

```
var list1 = (from a in db.candyStore 
         select brand);
var list2 = (from b in db.AnotherCandyStore
         select brand);

var list3 = (from c in db.supermarket
         select brand);

var princiapalList = (from a in db.candyStore 
         select brand)

var princiapalSet = new HAshSet<T>(princiapalList);
princiapalSet.ExceptWith(list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list2));
```

`princiapalSet` now contains only elements that are not in your lists.

Comment: Are you sure this will work with the provided lists? They look like Entity Framework queryables to me.

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting what he wants, but I think he wanted intersectWith instead of ExceptWith. Also, I think he only wants to compare against the brand property.

Comment: This assumes that the elements of `princiapalList` and the other queries are the same type AND that they implement `Equals` & `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Hey! yup i'm asking because i'm not sure if i can remove an item of  the queryables. is there a way for me to remove the elements i don't want and convert the whole thing to a queryable again?

Comment: @DionisMatos, why you want convert it to queryable again?

Comment: @Fabio because there is another snippet of code that will use the same queryable list as soon as it has all the rows needed. Is there a way to convert it to queryable?

Comment: Ok i got it! i made another queryable list, joined all the list i wanted to evaluate and got only the matching records using the where clause. Thanks so much guys! l

Answer (score 0):

You want to test for membership in the union of your lists.

```
principalSet.Where(x=>list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3).Contains(x));
```

For instance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it, i did not now i could join lists of type queryable, so it goes like this:

```
    var list1 = (from a in db.candyStore 
         select brand);
var list2 = (from b in db.AnotherCandyStore
         select brand);

var list3 = (from c in db.supermarket
         select brand);

var princiapalList = (from cs in list1
                       join acs in list2 on cs.BrandID equals acs.BrandID
                       join sm in list3 on sm.BrandID equals sm.BrandID
                       where cs.BrandID == acs.BrandID && cs.BrandID == sm.BrandID
                       select new { whatever }).toList();
```

Thanks for the help guys! i hope this helps other folks as well.